# Root Nexus 7 with 4.2.2

Tags: rooting, nexus-7

I'm trying to root a Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.2 (1st generation). I am following instructions here:
http://honai-android.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-root-nexus-7-on-android-422.html?showComment=1377379346836#c8791363668077143555
I get to Step 4 in which it says to wait until windows has finished installing drivers. I am on OS X. The Nexus 7 is in fast boot mode. It has an image of the green Android lying on its back with a panel open, in the upper right is "Start > corresponding to the on/off button" and just below that up and down arrows corresponding to the up/down volume buttons. I plugged in the USB and nothing happens, ie no indication of drivers being installed.

I watched this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0MyTvgfO7s
Which was somewhat helpful. Following the instructions enable me to see that the Nexus 7 was connected to the Mac in fastboot mode.
So I continued on to step 5, Running root-mac.sh resulted in this error in the terminal window:
... FAILED (remote: (Nv3pBadReceiveLength))
downloading 'boot.img'... FAILED (unknown status code)

Then from here [GUIDE][MAC/PC/LINUX][4.2] Unlock, Root and Flash Recovery at Android Central (sorry it won't let me put 2 links), I did the commands:
*./fastboot-mac oem unlock*
*./fastboot-mac oem reboot*

It did a clean install and reboot, but it is not rooted. When it was rebooting, the padlock icon was showing that it was unlocked. I test for root by trying to run the app Z-ScreenRecorder, which required root access.

**I got it.** After the unlock and reboot commands, then I went back to the original instructions and ran *CF-Auto-Root-grouper-nakasi-nexus7/root-mac.sh*.
Now the Z-ScreenRecorder app starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unlock the bootloader, root and add a custom/stock ROM, then you want to use Wugs Toolkit for Nexus. (Try to borrow or use a Windows PC or laptop, its not for OS X)

Here is XDA forum link: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475

Here is the download link (this is for Windows, not OS X)
http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/

Its pretty self explanatory, but try to read it all anyway.

*As far as I know there isn't a version for OS X*

I have used this method on my 2 Nexus 7s and my friends Nexus 4 & 5!!!

Happy rooting everyone!!!!

Comment: If I was wrong about OS X having a version,  my bad.

Answer (score -2):

Try to install framaroot, it's support many devices :) :)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2130276

Comment: The Nexus 7 is not on the list of compatible devices, though.